# What QueryLevel is used with which FunctionCode in I_NetLogonControl2 function?

Tags: winapi

If found [I_NetlogonControl2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-i_netlogoncontrol2?redirectedfrom=MSDN#netlogon_info_1-1) Windows API function but it's not clear of which `QueryLevel` is used with which `FunctionCode`?

TIA!!

Comment: It up to the information you need in the members from the `NETLOGON_INFO_1\2\3\4` structure. Indeed the msdn docs are not clear enough.